# [Image Processing]Thresholding Not Ignoring the transparent pixels

Tags: image, opencv, image-processing

Currently I am trying to crop the face along with hairs by the help of image segmentation methods, and then I have set all the non color pixels to be transparent, Then I am trying to apply `Binary Threshold` technique and `Adaptive Threshold`. But I am getting non-desirable results. Unfortunately the OpenCV methods are not ignoring the transparent pixels, and in documentation it is not defined how to handle this case, Any experienced help is appreciated (However I can replace the transparent pixels by a color value, provided I get the desired results)

Image 1.png(original Image with transparent background)
[image]

Image2.png(Image after applying simple binary threshold)
[image]

[image]
Image3.png(Image after adaptive threshold)

Clearly some image distortion/Noise is seen in the transparent areas of the image ?

Comment: use the alpha channel to create a `binary 8 bit mask` and use the `mask` parameter for all functions like `threshold` if they allow this parameter or create a temporary image that does ignore transparency and `.copyTo` your final result, using the `mask`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And I was able to solve this issue , I am posting this answer to help other fellow people for the educational purposes, and due to limited clarification about this thing, So the hack is to change the background color to be white(it worked in my case but you can surely choose some other background color), So now I colored all the pixels with alpha value 0 as while colored opaque pixels and then applied the required operations, And the outputs were as per expectation:

[image]

> Then applied some more image processing features to create this image out of this:

[image]